# RESTful resources and sub-resources in separate file with Jersey

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, embedded-jetty

I am running Jetty embedded server plus Jersey to serve a couple of RESTful resources. Here is how I configure Jersey inside the Jetty server:

```
ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);

servletHolder.setInitParameter(
    "com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass",
    "com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig");

servletHolder.setInitParameter(
    "com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages",
    "my.webservices.package");

servletHolder.setInitParameter(
    "com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
```

In my.webservices.package I have a couple of resource classes. One of these classes is annotated with @Path("/") and has one method that is annotated with @GET @Path("my/resource"):

```
@Path("/")
public class MyRootResource {
    @GET
    @Path("my/resource")
    public String myMethod() {...}
}
```

The other resource class is annotated with @Path("my/resource") and **does not have** a method annotated with ("/"):

```
@Path("/my/resource")
public class MyResourceResource {
    // some GET methods pointing to resources relative to the root of this class
}
```

So when I try to access http://*host*:port/*my-app*/my/resource, I expect that the request will hit my first class's myMethod() method. However, the server returns code 405 (method not allowed).

I believe that the Jersey dispatcher servlet forwards my request to the second class, ignoring that the first class already exposes this path.

Unfortunately I cannot put both implementation into one class. I am using Jersey version 1.17.1.

Is there a way that I can make Jersey look in both classes for this resource?

Thanks a lot!
Ivan

Comment: why can't you just move `myMethod()` to `MyResourceResource` at the root level (i.e. `@Path("/")`)?

Comment: I can't move the method either due to some other constraints